# why does my code get stuck in the middle?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a python beginner and found a exercise to play a local kids song using frequencies and duration.
the point is to use only once windsound.Beep, so I used a 'for' loop,
my code works but for some reason get stuck in the middle.
can somebody please point my problem?

```
freqs = {"la": 220, "si": 247, "do": 261, "re": 293, "mi": 329, "fa": 349, "sol": 392}
notes = "sol,250-mi,250-mi,500-fa,250-re,250-re,500-do,250-re,250-mi,250-fa,250-sol,250-sol,250- sol,500"
notes = notes.split('-')
print(notes)
import winsound
for note in notes:
    note_name = ''
    fre = ''
    for i in note:
        if i.isalpha():
            note_name = note_name + i
    elif i == ',':
        continue
    else:
        fre = fre + i
    winsound.Beep(freqs[note_name], int(fre))
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly give more details, as to on which line is the loop breaking. And probably your output too.

Comment: that's the thing, while running the pyCharm debugger. my code didn't break....

Comment: I don't have winsound loaded, but if I replace the call to winsound.beep with a print statement, it prints out the freq & time for all entries in notes.  The only thing I did notice was the last item results in a space before the fre value.  You can also significantly simplify your code by stripping the note value and then splitting on ",".  This leaves you with two items the name and fre value directly.